# How do you write $4(x +1)^2 + 1$ in the form $(ax +b)^2 + c\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, completing-the-square

We can write $4x^2+8x+5$ in the form $a(x+b)^2+c$ as $4(x+1)^2+1$. However, the question I am doing asks me to write it in the form $(ax+b)^2+c$. How do I change it to that form?

Comment: Write $4x^2$ as $(2x)^2$ and continue with the same process. You are on the right track :)

Comment: @SathvikAcharya Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: This question was upvoted by others because you showed what you tried, even if it was just one line. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and apply this advice to all the questions you ask.

Comment: Is the platform for all ages? Or is it for professionals and experts? I see many questions that are very complicated here @TobyMak

Comment: It's for all levels of mathematics. See [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17374/solution-to-my-question-exceeds-my-knowledge) for some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also solve the equation $(ax+b)^2+c\equiv 4x^2+8x+5$ (the $\equiv$ sign means "true for all values of $x$"—the coefficients on both sides of the equation have to be the same). If we expand the left-hand side, we get
$$
(ax+b)^2+c\equiv a^2x^2+2abx+(b^2+c)\equiv 4x^2+8x+5 \, .
$$
This means that $a^2=4$ and $2ab=8$ and $b^2+c=5$. If $a^2=4$ then $a=2$ or $a=-2$. Suppose that $a=2$. Then, $4b=8$, and so $b=2$. Finally, $4+c=5$, and so $c=1$. This gives us the solution
$$
(2x+2)^2+1\equiv 4x^2+8x+5 \, .
$$
If $a=-2$, then $-4b=8$, and so $b=-2$. Finally, $4+c=5$, and so $c=1$. This gives us the solution
$$
(-2x-2)^2+1 \equiv  4x^2+8x+5 \, .
$$
However, the first solution is arguably simpler because it doesn't have any minus signs in it.

Comment: Woah very helpful as well. Thanks for the help too @Joe !

Comment: @daisie: No worries! I'm glad I could help. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$4(x + 1)^2 = \bigg(2(x + 1)\bigg)^2$$
where I have used the identity $u^2 v^2 = (uv)^2$ as [coffeemath](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/483139) has noted.

Can you finish?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance, @Daisie!  =)

Answer (score 1):

If one has already found $a(x+b)^2+c$ form, then *provided* $a>0$ one can start by re-writing $a$ as $[\sqrt{a}]^2$ and use that $u^2v^2=(uv)^2$ to get to
$$ (\sqrt{a}\ x+\sqrt{a}\ b)^2+c.$$
This looks nicest when, as in your example, the original $a$ is a square, so there is no need for the "unsightly" square root symbol. So $(2x+2)^2+1.$

Comment: Thank you a lot. This helped me :)

Comment: @Daisie: If this helped you, you should accept any answer of the two by clicking on the "checkmark" button on the top left of the posts. This makes sure that other people who see this know that your query has been resolved.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Oh ok thank you for the tip! ^.^